# GCM works using Thread but does not work using AsyncTask

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-asynctask, google-cloud-messaging

I am new to Android Development

I am using class called GCMHelper to get the GCM code

In my login screen I used to call this class through Thread which works fine except it only runs at the end of the code which does not allow me to get the GCM code and work with it

Many people suggested that AsyncTask is the right thing to do, as it will be executed immediately when its called

I tried that but exact same method that worked in Thread did not work in AsyncTask, i get "***SERVICE_NOT_AVAILABLE***" exception

I wonder why and how to fix that??

Here is my code

```
private void LogMeIn(String LogReg, String EncEmail, String EncPwd, String EncUserID, String EncUserName) throws ExecutionException, InterruptedException {


    String gcmRegID = "";

    gcmRegID = new GCM().execute(null,null,null).get(); //----  AsyncTask

    GetGCM(); //----- Thread
  }



private void GetGCM() {
    Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                GCMHelper gcmRegistrationHelper = new GCMHelper(
                        getApplicationContext());
                String gcmRegID = "";
                gcmRegID = gcmRegistrationHelper.GCMRegister("12345678");
                gcmRegID = gcmRegID; // -------- Here I get code.. OK..
            } catch (Exception bug) {
                bug.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });

    thread.start();
}



private class GCM extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    private String resp;
    private Context context;
    //private ProgressDialog dialog;
    //private List<Message> messages;


    @Override
    protected String  doInBackground(String... params) {
        GCMHelper  gcmRegistrationHelper = new GCMHelper (
                getApplicationContext());
        String gcmRegID = "";
        try {
            gcmRegID = gcmRegistrationHelper.GCMRegister("12345678");
             //----------- Here is exception SERVICE_NOT_AVAILABLE
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return gcmRegID;
    }



}
```

and this is my GCMHelper Class

```
package com.asmgx.schlogger.app;

import android.content.Context;

import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil;
import com.google.android.gms.gcm.GoogleCloudMessaging;

/**
 * Created by ASMGX on 15/05/2016.
 */
public final  class GCMHelper {


    static GoogleCloudMessaging gcm = null;

    static Context context= null;

    public GCMHelper (Context context)
    {
        this.context= context;
    }

    public String GCMRegister (String SENDER_ID) throws Exception
    {
        String regid = "";
        //Check if Play store services are available.
        if(!checkPlayServices())
            throw new Exception("Google Play Services not supported. Please install and configure Google Play Store.");

        if (gcm == null) {
            gcm = GoogleCloudMessaging.getInstance(context);
        }
        regid = gcm.register(SENDER_ID);

        return regid;
    }


    private static boolean checkPlayServices() {
        int resultCode = GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(context);
        if (resultCode != ConnectionResult.SUCCESS) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

}
```

Comment: ok remove `.get();` method call then try it and override onPostExecute method for getting result on Ui Thread

Comment: after removing .get() I get "incompatible types" the gcmRegID is String while the other part is AsyncTask<String, String, String>    gcmRegID = new GCM().execute(null,null,null);

Comment: just use `new GCM().execute(null,null,null);` because execute method return type is void

Comment: Yes :) it works ... Many thanks

Comment: How can I mark your comment as an answer?